# What is a single word such that it is not too deserted and it conveys the meaning of "desiredly"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am after a word that is not too unknown and that can convey the meaning of "desiredly? Here "desiredly" is only used to make a point; I did some search and am under the impression that there is no such a word as "desiredly". So I would like to have a word that could be a suitable proxy for that.

An example would be:

> If you finish that sufficiently soon, then you will get paid "desiredly" soon.

(Here "desiredly" is to describe how soon this "you" specified ex ante; it is to be understood as "as desired".)

Just in case I have not made myself clear; the situation is like this: Suppose I employ someone and set the rule "Write down how long after you finished this job you would like to get paid; then I will set the time duration for you to finish it". It is in this sense I am trying to say "if you finish the job sufficiently soon, then you will get paid "desiredly" soon".

Comment: In practice I think most people would just say *The quicker you finish the job, the sooner you get paid.* If you truly intend to increase the number of days before you settle a contractor's invoice to the amount you're going to pay him (the number of days work you're signing him up for, clearly *not* his decision as to how long some task will take), you should use more words to explain (and perhaps *justify*) such an odd condition on the contract.

Answer (score 1):

We can actually use the world "desired" here by changing the word order:

> ...you will get paid as soon as you desire.

However, another phrasing might be less cumbersome.